# Foreach list of mysql query result

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to list down list of books grouped by author and populate the result in a radio button so that user will be able to select book belonged to different author. I manage to get the result and display the list like how I wanted it to be, but the radio button having the same name which making the user to only able to select `one` book even though the author is different.

My database table data looked something like this :

```
id  author  books
1  Author A  Book1
2  Author A  Book2
3  Author B  Book3
```

My current coding is as follow :

```
$sql = "SELECT author, GROUP_CONCAT(books SEPARATOR ',') as books FROM library GROUP BY author";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $books = explode(',',$row['books']);

        $i = 1;
        echo '<ul class="list-unstyled subjects">';
        echo '<li class="bordered" style="width: 30%;">'.$row['author'].'</li>';
        echo '<li class="bordered">';
        echo '<ul><li><input name="books" type="radio" value="" checked>N/A</li></ul>';

        foreach ($books as $book) {
            echo '<ul>';
            echo '<li><input name="books" type="radio" value="'.$book.'" />'.$book.'</li>';
            echo '</ul>';
        }

        echo '</li>';
        echo '</ul>';
        $i++;
    }
}

$sql = NULL;
```

So I am trying to put numbering at every end of the radio button name using the variable `$i` but it will make all the radio button to have a different name. I want to make it having same name for every group of author.

Comment: You seem to never use `$i`. Besides, setting the value of `$i` in the very same block in which you increment it makes the incrementation rather useless : `$i` will be always equal to 1, whatever happens. But once again, it won't break anything since you don't use it anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting `$i` back to `1` for each author. You need to initialize it *before* the `while` loop.

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $i = 1;
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $books = explode(',',$row['books']);

        echo '<ul class="list-unstyled subjects">';
        echo '<li class="bordered" style="width: 30%;">'.$row['author'].'</li>';
        echo '<li class="bordered">';
        echo '<ul><li><input name="books$i" type="radio" value="" checked>N/A</li></ul>';

        foreach ($books as $book) {
            echo '<ul>';
            echo '<li><input name="books$i" type="radio" value="'.$book.'" />'.$book.'</li>';
            echo '</ul>';
        }

        echo '</li>';
        echo '</ul>';
        $i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: I did not putting the `$i` because I have no idea where to place it. By the way, I've tried your solution and that's just what I'm looking for. Thank you!